# GraphQLSchema Specified key does not exist on `amplify push`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I have upgraded amplify version from `4.45.0` to `5.2.0`,

Now when I do `amplify push`, I am getting the following error:

```
Following resources failed

Resource Name: ci5lt23eofhvxlc3an7db4d7veGraphQLSchema (AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema)
Event Type: update
Reason: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: GZQF1T9HWCCED75H; S3 Extended Request ID: qicfcwF2YUNdqMDU3EUkt+hsXIQawcirDG7TIX+peEEkAWOE1v9ee6n2L5Qc2I8uePyAXg2eJ4U=; Proxy: null)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removed error after pushing it with force as: `amplify push --force`

Answer (score 1):

Forcefully pushing to the cloud did not help in my case.
Turns out my graphql secret key has an expiration period which i realized after running `amplify update api` and here it was:

```
Authorization modes
- Default: API key expiring Tue Oct 25 2022 ....
```

then I renewed my key. it worked out fine...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I found out that it was due to this part on the `graphQL` file :

This "input" configures a global authorization rule to enable public access to all models in this schema. Learn more about authorization rules here: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules

```
input AMPLIFY { globalAuthRule: AuthRule = { allow: public } } # FOR TESTING ONLY!
```

```
type User @model {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    email: String!
}
```

the solution is to remove everything before `type` then do `amplify-push` on your shell